# How to find the number of pages scraped by spider

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy in Python to scrape data from website.

I successfully scraped data from website but I want to know how many pages did my spider scrape.

Scrapy stats is as follow:
[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: is it necessary to show the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `scrapy` uses `requests` to ask for a page and gets `responses` from the webserver the statistics labeled as such are informative.

```
downloader/request_count: 421
downloader/response_count: 421
downloader/response_status_count/200: 420
downloader/response_status_count/404: 1
```

So `scrapy` made 421 requests and got 420 times a valid response (code 200). One time there was no reponse (code 404).

Answer (score 0):

420 pages.

You can determine this from the `downloader/response_status_count/200` field of the stats.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please let me know what does downloader/response_count : 421 mean?